# Get data entries in a range from mongodb by pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I hope to get the certain range entries of data from mongodb, because all the data is too huge. For example, I need to get the range between 1000-2000.

I use the $range in mongodb aggregation to get the certain range of data entries.

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
database = client['abc_data']
print database.users.count() # this is a huge number
cursor_mongo = database.users.aggregate({$range:[0, 100]}, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Hope to get the cursor including the data range from 0 to 100. But got the error:

```
cursor_mongo = database.stackoverflow_users.aggregate({$range:[0, 100]}, allowDiskUse=True)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) syntax is bad (but you already knew that!)

To sum up :

- Aggregation takes an array of **[stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)** as pipeline.
- each stage can use aggregation **[operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)**

Now, your explanation is not clear : what is your range? the value of a field? Or only the number / position of documents you want to retrieve?

**IN BOTH CASES, you don't need aggregation!**

If it represents the value of a field, you can achieve with the following query :

```
db.collection.find({"fieldName":{$gte:100,$lt:200}})
```

If it's the number and position of docs,

```
db.collection.find().skip(100).limit(100)
```

Note : i used 100 and 200 as range start and end, to figure the use of skip method

Comment: Thanks, I have use find + skip for instead. range is not a correct command